# Getting more results using value from previous query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have a table like this:

```
+---------+----------+
| post_id | reply_to |
+---------+----------+
|       1 |        0 |
|       2 |        1 |
|       3 |        2 |
|       4 |        2 |
|       5 |        3 |
|       6 |        5 |
|       7 |        1 |
|       8 |        7 |
|       9 |        8 |
|      10 |        7 |
+---------+----------+
```

`reply_to` is simply the ID of the post that is being replied to (i.e. `post_id` of 2 is a reply to `post_id` of 1).

This is what it looks like when put into nested-form:

```
1
    2
        3
            5
                6
        4
    7
        8
            9
        10
```

How can I create a *single query* that does the following:

- **Query 1:** Get all posts that are replies to `post_id = 1` (`2 and 7`) and limit the number of results to 5
- **Query 2:** Using the retrieved values from **query 1**, get the children posts (`3 and 4`, and `8 and 10`) and limit the number of results to 3 *per parent post*
- **Query 3:** Using the retrieved values from **query 2**, get the children posts (`5` and `9`) and limit the number of results to 1 *per parent post*

So in the end, the result should include these post_ids: `2, 3, 5, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10`.

Here's the SQL Fiddle I've created: **http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/23edc/21**

Please help!

Comment: What purpose does a single query serve? It seems as though it only adds unnecessary complexity.

Comment: It looks like you can use a single SP(Stored Procedure) to solve your requirement.

Comment: Are you sure you don't like the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/27454902/4350148? It does the  job. Take another look and comment.

Answer (score 0):

This works in SQL Server, and I think it is generic SQL, but I cannot get SQL Fiddle to work right now.

```
create table test1 (post_id int, reply_to int);

insert into test1 (post_id, reply_to) values
(1,0),(2,1),(3,2),(4,2),(5,3),(6,5),(7,1),(8,7),(9,8),(10,7),
(11,2),(12,2),(13,2),(14,3); /* Added records to test conditions */

/* All replies to post_id=1 */
with q1 as (
    select post_id
    from test1
    where reply_to = 1
)
/* Top 3 replies to all results in q1 */
, q2 as (
    select
            q1.post_id as parent_post,
            t1.post_id as child_post,
            count(*) as row_num
    from test1 as t1
        inner join q1 on t1.reply_to = q1.post_id
        left outer join test1 as t2 on t1.reply_to = t2.reply_to 
                and t1.post_id >= t2.post_id
    group by q1.post_id, t1.post_id
    having count(*) <= 3
)
/* Get 0 or 1 grandchild posts */
, q3 as (
    select
            q2.parent_post,
            q2.child_post,
            t1.post_id as grandchild_post,
            count(*) as row_num
    from q2
        left outer join test1 as t1 on q2.child_post = t1.reply_to
        left outer join test1 as t2 on t1.reply_to = t2.reply_to 
                and t1.post_id >= t2.post_id
    group by q2.parent_post, q2.child_post, t1.post_id
    having count(*) = 1
)
/* Aggregate the different post ids */
select distinct parent_post as post_id from q3
union
select distinct child_post from q3
union
select distinct grandchild_post from q3 
        where grandchild_post is not null;

drop table test1;
```